# 複数tar内容を個別ディレクトリに配置して単一tarファイルを再構成したい

Tags: linux, centos

複数個のtarファイル（正確にはtar.bz2）が存在するとき、各tarファイルが内包するファイル群を単一のtarファイル（こちらもtar.bz2）に再構成したいです。

このとき、入力tarファイル群のファイル名部分をサブ・ディレクトリ名とし、出力tarファイル内では各サブ・ディレクトリ配下に入力tarファイル内容がそれぞれ配置されるようにしたいと考えています。

入出力tarファイルのイメージは下記の通りです：

```
入力tarファイル群
$ ls
aaa.tar.bz2  bbb.tar.bz2  ccc.tar.bz2
$ tar -tf aaa.tar.bz2
./123
$ tar -tf bbb.tar.bz2
./XYZ
$ tar -tf ccc.tar.bz2
./日本語

期待する出力tarファイル
$ tar -tf repacking.tar.bz2
./aaa/123
./bbb/XYZ
./ccc/日本語
```

一旦全ての入力tarファイル群を展開し、その後で出力tarファイルを再構成していけば実現は可能なのですが、ディスク使用量を抑えるという観点から、なるべくファイルを展開しないですむ解法はないものでしょうか。

実行環境：

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
$ tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.26
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python(version 2.7.11) を使ってみました。

**concat_tbz2.py**

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

import os.path
import sys
import tarfile

out = tarfile.open(sys.argv[1], mode='w:bz2')
for tf in sys.argv[2:]:
  dir = os.path.basename(tf).split('.')[0]
  tar = tarfile.open(tf, mode='r')
  for m in tar:
    m.name = dir + '/' + m.name
    out.addfile(m, fileobj=tar.extractfile(m))
  tar.close()

out.close()
```

**使用例**

```bash
$ ./concat_tbz2.py repacking.tar.bz2 aaa.tar.bz2 bbb.tar.bz2 ccc.tar.bz2
$ tar -tf repacking.tar.bz2
aaa/123
bbb/XYZ
ccc/日本語
```

まぁ、エラーチェックは省いて最低限動作するだけのシロモノですので、気を付けてご使用下さい。

Comment: シェルスクリプト＋tarコマンド前提で模索していたので、Python利用は思いつきませんでした。まさか標準ライブラリでtarfileいじれるとは、さすがBattery Included言語ですね。